# Making picturebox preform a function when clicked VB6

Tags: vb6

I have a picturebox on my form. When I click on it, I want it to preform a function (in this case, setting a value to a variable). I, however, have not found any way to do this.

The picturebox, should during runtime, when clicked, set a value to a variable.

I have considered putting a textbox over the picturebox and making it transparent, but I have not found a way to make textboxes transparent via visual basic. There should be a more direct way available?

Can I get some help? Thanks.

Comment: A picture box *has* a click event: `Private Sub Picture1_Click()
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can double click on the picture box and it will bring up the code. From there insert the code you want

```
Private sub picture1_click() 

End sub
```